# composition avec le passé composé

Tags: prépositions, passé-composé

Bonjour, je suis débutant et j'ai écrit un composition pour exercer le passé composé, mais je ne sais pas si j'ai utilisé les préposition et les contraction corrects. J'ai ete reconnaisant si quelqu'un pouvait lire la composition et dit moi si elle est grammaticalement correct et si ce text aussi est correct, s'il vous plait.

Je suis à Paris ou j'ai fait beaucuop de choses. D'abord je suis monté à la Tour Eiffel. Ensuite j'ai pris le bateau mouche. Aprés je suis allé à la Place de la Concorde et depuis j'ai vu l'Arc de Triumphe. Dans le soir je suis sorti avec des amis et nous avons visité l'église Notre Dame ou nous avons acheté beaucoup de souvenirs. Aprés nous avons regardé à un film en francais. Finalment nous sommes retourné a l'hotel et nous avons couché.

Comment: On dit "Dans la soirée" plutôt que "Dans le soir". De même, si tu veux dire que vous êtes allés au lit tu dirais "nous nous sommes couchés", puisque "j'ai couché avec X" veut dire que tu as eu des rapports avec X. A part ça et quelques typo, ton emploi du passé composé est correct.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Le passé composé est utilisé correctement, en dehors du pittoresque **nous avons couché** et de l'accord manquant à **retourné**. Il y a en revanche pas mal de petites corrections possibles sur d'autres points que le passé composé :

> Je suis à Paris **où** j'ai fait **beaucoup** de choses. **D'abord,** je suis monté à la Tour Eiffel. **Ensuite,** j'ai pris **un** **bateau-mouche**. **Après,** je suis allé à la **place** de la Concorde et **de là** j'ai vu l'Arc de **Triomphe**. **Le soir,** je suis sorti avec des amis et nous avons visité **la cathédrale Notre-Dame** **où** nous avons acheté beaucoup de souvenirs. **Après,** nous avons **regardé un** film en **français** (ou en **VF**). **Finalement,** nous sommes **retournés** **à** **l'hôtel** et nous **nous sommes couchés**.

Answer (score -1):

Je suis à Paris où j'ai fait beaucoup de choses. D'abord je suis monté à la Tour Eiffel. Ensuite j'ai pris le bateau mouche. Aprés je suis allé à la Place de la Concorde et **puis** (not *depuis*) j'ai vu l'Arc de Tri**o**mphe. Dans **la soirée** (not *le soir*) je suis sorti avec des amis et nous avons visité l'église Notre Dame ou nous avons acheté beaucoup de souvenirs. Aprés nous avons regardé (*no "à" here*) un film en francais. Finalment nous sommes retournés a l'hôtel et **nous nous sommes couchés** (not *nous avons couché*).

There's a difference between the verbs **coucher**, au passé composé : j'ai couché (avec) : *having sex (with)*, and **se coucher**, au passé composé : je me suis couché : *going to bed*.